# NameError: name 'next_point' is not defined

Tags: python

My code below shows this:

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\CROMUL~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22212/4255635961.py in 
----> 1 if next_point == game['food']:
2     eat(snake)
3 else:
4     game['snake'].popleft()

NameError: name 'next_point' is not defined

```
def move_snake(direction):
snake = set(game['snake'])
u, w = game['snake'][-1]
next_point = MOVEMENTS[direction](u, w)

    if next_point == game['food']:
    eat(snake)
else:
    game['snake'].popleft()
```

Comment: Your current formating of the code does not help up. Please edit the code section with the actual indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's indentation is wonky.

Try this:

```
def move_snake(direction):
    snake = set(game['snake'])
    u, w = game['snake'][-1]
    next_point = MOVEMENTS[direction](u, w)

    if next_point == game['food']:
        eat(snake)
    else:
        game['snake'].popleft()
```